# Error: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException Unable to connect to localhost/<unresolved>

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis

I'm trying this tutorial from a book where there's an api running and when the application with the redis code gets called, it's suppose to output the information from the api.  However, this is the error I get when I run the application:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to localhost/<unresolved>:6379
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.translateException(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1689) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1597) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getNativeConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1383) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1366) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getSharedConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1093) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:421) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at com.demo.springdataexample.demo.PlaneFinderPoller.pollPlanes(PlaneFinderPoller.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to localhost/<unresolved>:6379
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:78) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.8.RELEASE.jar:6.1.8.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:56) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.8.RELEASE.jar:6.1.8.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.getConnection(AbstractRedisClient.java:330) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.8.RELEASE.jar:6.1.8.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:216) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.8.RELEASE.jar:6.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.lambda$getConnection$1(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:115) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.getConnection(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:115) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1595) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

Below is the code:

Main class:

```
package com.demo.springdataexample.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisOperations;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SburRedisApplication {
    @Bean
    public RedisOperations<String, Aircraft>
    redisOperations(RedisConnectionFactory factory) {
        Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<Aircraft> serializer =
                new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Aircraft.class);

        RedisTemplate<String, Aircraft> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(factory);
        template.setDefaultSerializer(serializer);
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());

        return template;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SburRedisApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

PlaneFinderPoller.java

```
package com.demo.springdataexample.demo;

import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisOperations;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

@EnableScheduling
@Component
public class PlaneFinderPoller {
    private WebClient webclient =
            WebClient.create("http://localhost:7634/aircraft");

    private final RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    private final RedisOperations<String, Aircraft> redisOperations;

    public PlaneFinderPoller(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                             RedisOperations<String, Aircraft> redisOperations)
    {
        this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
        this.redisOperations = redisOperations;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate =  1000)
    private  void pollPlanes(){
        connectionFactory.getConnection().serverCommands().flushDb();

        webclient.get()
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Aircraft.class)
                .filter(plane -> !plane.getReg().isEmpty())
                .toStream()
                .forEach(ac -> redisOperations.opsForValue().set(ac.getReg(), ac));

        redisOperations.opsForValue()
                .getOperations()
                .keys("*")
                .forEach(ac -> System.out.println(redisOperations.opsForValue().get(ac)));
    }
}
```

Aircraft.java

Comment: As it's connectivity issue so can you provide more information? Where is the redis server running? Where did you configure the redis host name and corresponding port?

Comment: the redis server is running locally.  The book didn't specify where to put the redis host name and port so I think it's running on 8080.

Comment: So looks like you haven't spin the redis server yet. Your application is looking for redis server availability at localhost on port 6379

Comment: is there a link that would show me how to do that?

Comment: You can download it from `https://redis.io/download/`. Example for setup for windows `https://redis.com/blog/redis-on-windows-10/` . You can easily find the setup procedure for other OS.

Answer (score 0):

I find that book author in this issue says running redis:
https://github.com/mkheck/SpringBootUpAndRunning/issues/1